# What am I doing wrong in this bash script?

Tags: bash

I'd like to know what's wrong with my code? What am I missing? Why isn't the `IF` statement working correctly? Why does it show one output only? Why isn't the `elif` statement working? I am trying to host 3 servers, www.ee and www.eu and www.com and then host them again to determine whether they have IPv6 addres or mail server.

EDIT: It's supposed to work like this:

1) Create script named nimed.sh

2) At the input, the host executes .ee; .eu; .com hosts.

3) If host doesn't exist, print`"Host not found"`

4) The host address will first display the corresponding email server address it found. `(Use commands sort, awk, tail or head)`. Must remove dots on the end of the host sentence. Like, it shows like this: ?.com. (removing the dot = ?.com)

5) If mail server was not found then print `"mail server not found"`

6) If mail server was found then ask mail server IP address with host command.

7) If mail server got IPv6 address then print `"found IPv6"`, if not then print `"IPv6 not found"`

That is what I need to do and I'm stuck at part 7. It's a school exercise to learn bash by doing exercises. It's optional, not mandatory.

```
#!/bin/bash

m1="has address"
m2="has IPv6 address"
m3="mail is handled by 0 ."
m4="found IPv6"
m5="IPv6 not found"
m6="mail server not found"
###########################################################################################################################
host "$(host www.ee | sort | grep "mail is handled" | head -1 | awk '{print $7}')" >> www.all.txt
#first line shows this to www.all.txt
#aspmx.l.google.com has address 108.177.14.26
#aspmx.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b
host "$(host www.eu | sort | grep "mail is handled" | head -1 | awk '{print $7}')" >> www.all.txt
#second line shows this to www.all.txt
#mail.www.eu has address 46.105.44.68
host "$(host www.com | sort | grep "mail is handled" | head -1 | awk '{print $7}')" >> www.all.txt
#third line shows this to www.all.txt
#ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has address 108.177.14.26
#ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b
file="www.all.txt" #and this file has this in total:
#aspmx.l.google.com has address 108.177.14.26
#aspmx.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b
#mail.www.eu has address 46.105.44.68
#ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has address 108.177.14.26
#ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c03::1b
while read line #now this is where it gets messy. I don't know what to do-
#with line variable
do
    if grep -q "$m2" $file #if string 'has IPv6 address' is in www.all.txt
    then
        awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' #go to line 1 and print the first text
# aspmx.l.google.com
        echo "${m4}" #print 'Found IPv6'
    elif grep -q "$m1" $file; then #else if string 'has address' is in
# www.all.txt then
        awk 'NR==2 {print $1}' #go to line 2 and print the first text
        echo "${m5}" #print 'IPv6 not found'
    elif grep -q "$m3" $file; then #if string 'mail is handled by 0 .'
#is in www.all.txt then
        echo "${m6}" #print 'mail server does not exist'
    else #if none of the above was correct then
        echo "${m6}" #mail server does not exist and
        echo "${m5}" #IPv6 not found
    fi #end the if-elif-else statement
done < $file #end the while loop
```

File that it creates:

```
kristen@kristen-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ ./nimed.sh
aspmx.l.google.com
found IPv6
kristen@kristen-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ ls
koopia.sh  nimed.sh  TEST.sh  www.all.txt
kristen@kristen-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ cat www.all.txt 
aspmx.l.google.com has address 64.233.161.26
aspmx.l.google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::1b
mail.www.eu has address 46.105.44.68
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has address 64.233.161.26
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4010:c0e::1b
kristen@kristen-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$
```

TEST 1: Success

```
Correct program output
--- Input ---

 www.ee


--- Program output ---

aspmx.l.google.com
found IPv6


--- Expected output (text)---

aspmx.l.google.com
found IPv6
```

TEST 2: Failed

```
Incorrect program output
--- Input ---

 www.eu


--- Program output ---

aspmx.l.google.com
Found IPv6


--- Expected output (text)---

mail.www.eu
Didn't find IPv6
```

Comment: Add some debugging echos & exit status checks, and your script will show you. Or there's a bash set that acts similar

Comment: The logic of the program is pretty confused. First, it doesn't take input at all -- the `host` commands *always* run for all three domains. Second, it's not clear what the `while read` loop is supposed to do -- it doesn't do anything at all with the `$line` variable it read from the file, and I'm not sure what you'd do with it anyway. Third, the `grep` commands read the entire file (not the single line), and the `awk` command reads from the same source the loop does (that's why the loop runs once, `read` reads the first line, then `awk` reads the rest). I'm not clear how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I see. Thank you @GordonDavisson I'll try to search for something else to change the logic of read and awk.

Comment: Can you explain how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yeah! Absolutely. I edited the code and put comments to every line and I hope it makes it even clear.

Comment: You may want to use this: https://www.shellcheck.net/ to improve your script

Comment: Shellcheck.net is nice and good but I'm looking for the answer and solution if possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because debugging very specific scripts does not help any future visitor of Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a while, I got it working. I made one grave mistake and didn't read the text correctly. Well, it was one easy peasy exercise when I found out that I need to use **`read`** :D.

**Here's the answer to my question:**

```
#!/bin/bash

m1="has address"
m2="has IPv6 address"
m3="mail is handled by 0 ."
m4="on IPv6"
m5="ei ole IPv6"
m6="mailiserverit pole"
m7="NXDOMAIN"
f="www.all.txt"
read -p "Sisesta host: " hostname
host $hostname | sort > $f
if grep -q "$m3" $f; then
        echo "$m6"
        echo "$m5"
elif grep -q "$m2" $f; then
        awk 'NR==3 {print $7}' $f
        echo "$m4"
elif host "$(host $hostname | sed 's/\.$//' | tail -1 | awk '{print $7}')" > www.all.txt && grep -q "mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net" $f; then
        awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' $f
        echo "$m5"
elif grep -q "$m7" $f; then
        echo "hosti pole"
else
        host "$(host $hostname | sed 's/\.$//' | sort | awk 'NR==2 {print $7}')" > $f
                if grep -q "$m2" $f; then
                        awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' $f
                        echo "$m4"
                elif grep -q "$m1" $f; then
                        awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' $f
                        echo "$m5"
fi
        fi
```